# How to change drupal 8 REST API core messages

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am using following **PATCH** request to update password:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "type": {
      "href": "{url}/rest/type/user/user"
    }
  },
  "pass": [
    {
    "existing":"admin",
    "value":"123456789"
    }]
}
```

If the existing password is wrong then drupal return the message like

```
Unprocessable Entity: validation failed.pass: Your current password is missing or incorrect; it's required to change the Password.
```

I want to remove this "**Unprocessable Entity:**" stuff and want show clear message to user like

```
Your current password is missing or incorrect; it's required to change the Password.
```

Any help is very appreciate.